# Old 6 speed casette on a new modern wheel

Tags: rims, vintage

I've had this old Batavus sprint bike sitting in the shed for years, and recently got into road racing. So I've bought a newish used modern road race bike and recently upgraded it's wheels. Since the old wheels were just lying around I tried fitting them to the good 'ol Batavus.

They were a little squeeze (research has shown there's a 4mm difference.. 126mm vs 130mm on the newer ones), but I got them in fine.

Of course, the only problem is is that there's no cassette on the rear wheel I fitted. My question is, can I fit the old cassette on this new wheel? Or will the cassette body be totally different? Or can a cassette body be transferred to the new wheel? I'm not sure how that stuff works.

It's a Shimano 600 6-speed setup.

Comment: You can get 126 mm wheels still from companies like velo orange, but Harris Cyclery among other places still sell 6 speed freewheels. But a decent amount of people have 130mm wheels running fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old "cassette" is most likely a freewheel. You can see the difference between a cassette and freewheel [here](http://sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html)

So no, I don't think you will be able to use the old freewheel on the newish wheels (they probably take cassettes). You can just buy a new cassette though (they're cheap), assuming what I said was correct.

Comment: Yeah, it's a freewheel. But then how do I go about this? The new wheel had a modern Shimano 105 9 speed casette on it, which is now on the even newer rim ofcourse. Can you buy 6-speed casettes that fit over the casette body?

Comment: Can I just get a 9 speed or 10 speed casette and a new chain? The bike is running shimano downtube friction shifters.

Comment: Yeah, the great thing about friction shifters is that they don't care about how many speeds you are running. I would just get a 9 speed cassette that you like and throw that on there.